# jQuery Mobile Slider issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 4 sliders that are supposed to add up to 100.  If the user slides the top three sliders and the combine to a total of 75, the fourth slider should be able to be more than that.  I currently have the logic set up to stop counting when the slider reaches the amount, but I can't get the slider to stop.

[Here is an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mysticgohan53/A2YsU/1/)

Can anyone tell me why the sliders won't stop sliding?  I'm sure it's probably something relatively easy that I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/wroniasty/A2YsU/2/

I believe calling `val()` within `change` handler is causing the problems.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that works exactly the way I want it to, but I keep getting an "uncaught rangeError" message. http://jsfiddle.net/mysticgohan53/A2YsU/16/